# Prepositional phrase directly after antecedent or after the verb group?

Tags: prépositions

While correcting some texts in French, I came across the following problem. One person has written the following sentence:

> une déviation est prévue via le complexe de bretelles d'Ekeren

while the other one has translated that same sentence as

> une déviation via le complexe de bretelles d'Ekeren est prévue.

The word group with "via" is in a different place. Both sentences sound fine to me but I'm not sure if my gut feeling is correct or if there's a difference in nuance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight nuance, but it's ambiguous.

> Une déviation via le complexe de bretelles d'Ekeren est prévue.

This is the default statement, with no particular emphasis. However, it is awkward because the subject is very long (“*Une déviation via le complexe de bretelles d'Ekeren*”). It would be better to use the active voice: “*On a prévu une déviation via le complexe de bretelles d'Ekeren*” (or “*on prévoit*”, or a different subject, depending on the context).

> Une déviation est prévue via le complexe de bretelles d'Ekeren.

Ostensibly, a diversion is planned. And incidentally, this deviation will go via Ekeren. However, because putting the “*via …*” clause in the subject is awkward, this doesn't necessarily de-emphasise the via part.

To explicitly put emphasis on Ekeren, a possible turn of phrase would be

> Le complexe de bretelles d'Ekeren est prévu comme déviation.

Comment: a diversion is planned? Did you mean detour? déviation in road construction in French is a detour in English...

Comment: @Lambie It's a *detour* in AmE, but a *diversion* in BrE. See [diversion signs](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=diversion+sign&sa=X) (mostly yellow, many on .uk) with [detour signs](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=detour+sign&sa=X) (mostly orange, mostly on .com).

Comment: Whoops. Yes, they do use diversion in the UK. I didn't know that. But not deviation. https://www.roads.org.uk/articles/emergency-diversion-routes

Comment: @Lambie Deviation is occasionally used in AuE. e.g. https://youngsbusservice.com.au/route-delays-and-deviations-due-to-roadworks/

Answer (score 1):

I would say the order is free here and doesn't introduce any (significant) nuance.